# Сортировка по заданному условию pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть таблица с городами (объект `pandas.DataFrame` с единственным столбцом `'city'`) table и объект `pandas.Series` - `cities`, являющийся первым столбцом этой таблицы (`cities = table['city']`).

Мне необходимо отсортировать `cities` таким образом, чтобы в нем остались только слова, удовлетворяющие данному условию. В данном случае мне нужно оставить в `cities` только города, начинающиеся с буквы `'м'`. Мне нужно что-то аналогичное нижеописанному действию, но только при помощи pandas, а не списков:

```
lst = [word for word in cities if word[0] == 'м']
```

Как я могу осуществить это? Я пробовал это, но оно выдает мне KeyError: False

```
lst = table.loc[cities[0] == 'м']
```

Хотя, если нужно оставить только поля с заданным значением, то это работает:

```
lst= table.loc[cities != 'магадан']
```

Каким образом в объекте `pandas.Series` возможно оставить только поля, начинающиеся с заданной буквы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [250]: table
Out[250]:
        city
0    магадан
1       Киев
2  Мариуполь
3  Запорожье
4     Москва
```

Варианты решения:

```
In [252]: table[table['city'].str.lower().str.startswith('м')]
Out[252]:
        city
0    магадан
2  Мариуполь
4     Москва
```

или при помощи регулярных выражений:

```
In [253]: table[table['city'].str.contains('^м', flags=re.I)]
Out[253]:
        city
0    магадан
2  Мариуполь
4     Москва

In [254]: table[table['city'].str.match('^м.*$', flags=re.I)]
Out[254]:
        city
0    магадан
2  Мариуполь
4     Москва
```

Comment: Хорошечно. Спасибо